# Как передать переменную из класса в класс

Tags: java

Я работаю над проектом и мне нужно передать переменную из класса `JavaReactor` в класс `GameGraphicsAndDigitalOperations`.

Но когда я это пытаюсь сделать мне в классе `GameGraphicsAndDigitalOperations` выдаёт 0.

Код:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class JavaReactor extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JavaReactor frame = new JavaReactor();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public int i;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    public int Heat_reactor = 10;
    public int Energy_reactor = 0;
    public JComboBox comboBox;
    public int getIndex;

    public JavaReactor() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 0, 1200, 878);
        contentPane = new GameGraphicsAndDigitalOperations();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        GameGraphicsAndDigitalOperations GGADO = new GameGraphicsAndDigitalOperations();

        comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setFont(new Font("standard 09_66", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        comboBox.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        comboBox.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        comboBox.setBounds(934, 26, 240, 20);
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                getIndex = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
                System.out.println(getIndex+" "+e);
        }});
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(GGADO.aBuy));
        contentPane.add(comboBox);

        JLabel lblBay = new JLabel("Buy:");
        lblBay.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\\u0412\u043B\u0430\u0434\u0438\u043A\\Desktop\\Make reactor java IMG\\Buy.png"));
        lblBay.setFont(new Font("standard 09_66", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        lblBay.setBounds(849, 13, 130, 46);
        contentPane.add(lblBay);

        JLabel lblE = new JLabel("Energy:");
        lblE.setFont(new Font("standard 09_66", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        lblE.setBounds(849, 814, 95, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblE);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setEditable(false);
        textField_1.setBounds(934, 749, 240, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setBounds(934, 811, 240, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField.setText(Integer.toString(Energy_reactor));
        textField_1.setText(Integer.toString(Heat_reactor));

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Heat -1");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(Heat_reactor!=0)
                {
                    Heat_reactor--;
                    textField_1.setText(Integer.toString(Heat_reactor));
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setFont(new Font("standard 09_66", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        btnNewButton_1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(849, 780, 325, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);

        JLabel lblHeat = new JLabel("Heat:");
        lblHeat.setFont(new Font("standard 09_66", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        lblHeat.setBounds(849, 755, 95, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblHeat);
        /*Timer t = new Timer(1500,new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {*/
        //System.out.println(getIndex);
        //getIndex = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
        /*}});*/
        //t.start();
    }
    public int gi()
    {
        return getIndex;
    }
}
class GameGraphicsAndDigitalOperations extends JPanel
{
    public String[] aBuy = {"Heat exchanger 50$","Heat inlet 200$","Heat outlet 200$","Heat vent 50$","Reactor rod Uranus 5$"};
    public int CombotBoxGetSelect;
    public int XDRAWPOLE = 1;
    public int YDRAWPOLE = 1;
    public int getI;
    Boolean b=false;
    public GameGraphicsAndDigitalOperations()
    {
        addMouseListener(new myMouse1());
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Image f = null;
        try{f = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Владик\\Desktop\\Make reactor java IMG\\Pole.png"));}
        catch(IOException ex){}
        g.drawImage(f,1,1,null);
        while(XDRAWPOLE<=20)
        {
            g.drawImage(f,XDRAWPOLE*40,1,null);
            XDRAWPOLE++;
        }
        XDRAWPOLE = 1;
        while(YDRAWPOLE<=20)
        {
            g.drawImage(f,1,YDRAWPOLE*40,null);
            while(XDRAWPOLE<=20)
            {
                g.drawImage(f,XDRAWPOLE*40,YDRAWPOLE*40,null);
                XDRAWPOLE++;
            }
            XDRAWPOLE = 1;
            YDRAWPOLE++;
        }
        YDRAWPOLE = 1;
        try{f = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Владик\\Desktop\\Make reactor java IMG\\Heat_vent_1.png"));}
        catch(IOException ex){}
        if(b)
        {
            g.drawImage(f,5,5,32,32,null);
        }
    }
    public class myMouse1 implements MouseListener
    {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {

        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
        {

        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
        {

        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            JavaReactor Per = new JavaReactor();
            getI = Per.getIndex;
            int tX = e.getX();
            int tY = e.getY();
            int col = e.getClickCount();
            int btn = e.getButton();
            Per.repaint();
            System.out.println(Per.comboBox.getSelectedItem());
            if((tX>=1)&&(tX<=40)&&(tY>=1)&&(tY<=40)&&(col==1)&&(btn==1)&&(getI==3))
            {
                b=true;
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос можно улучшить, если [убрать портянку из кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

Вы создали новый экземпляр `JavaReactor` и немедленно попытались прочитать значение поля `getIndex`, которое (как и положено) инициализируется значением `0`

Нужное вам значение можно прочитать только после того, как будет вызван `ActionListener` у комбобокса.